# "undo" pivot table with ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, attribute-joins, table

I have a table in a geodatabase with an ID and a text field for each day of a week. The text fields contains 0 or 1 for monday, 0 or 2 for tuesday, and so on. One ID can have multiple day entries, so for every day, or only on weekends,...

I need to join this information to another table. It contains a Name, and the ID of the first table. At the end, it should have the following fields: Name, ID, Day. and the day information are coming from the seven "day-fields" and if one ID has multiple day entries it has to be duplicated.

Is there a possibility to do this, or do I need to create seven distinct tables and re-assemble them afterwards?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.